# Read temporary file with FileReader and BufferedReader - Eclipse Java Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a strange problem with read of a temporary file.
I create a new temp file:

```
File fileTemp = File.createTempFile("cex_data", ".txt");
```

After that, I write into it and if I call fileTemp.getAbsolutePath() and find it on disk is all ok. The file is created and written.

I call now another function:

```
 readFromCexFile(fileTemp);
```

And in this function I would read file:

```
        FileReader f;
        BufferedReader b;
        String filePath = fileTemp.getAbsolutePath();       
        //filePath = "C:\\tempPath/cex_data7121025199294655326.txt";
        f = new FileReader(filePath);
        b = new BufferedReader(f);
        String s1;
        while(true) 
        {
            s1 = b.readLine();
            ....
            if(s1=="")
                break;
        }
```

The problem was that is I use fileTemp.getAbsolutePath() doesn't read anything. However, if I use `filePath = "C:\\tempPath/cex_data7121025199294655326.txt";` is all ok.

I tried also to print `fileTemp.getAbsolutePath()` and then replace "\" and "/" to be equals `filePath = "C:\\tempPath/cex_data7121025199294655326.txt"` syntax, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is `getCanonicalPath()` different from `getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader(java.io.File)) constructor.

```
f = new FileReader(fileTemp);
```

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you better.